# How remove duplicate profile?

Tags: iphone, ios8

When i am trying to generate .ipa file it gives following issue.

[image]

How to remove duplicate profile?.

Please help me to solve this issue...

Thanks......

Comment: I guess you use Automatic in provisioning profiles. If you does, select proper one instead of Automatic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iPhone Configuration Utility.

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Then select Provisioning Profiles in the left pane and remove ones you don't need.

[image]